# PHPMail não recebe conteúdo dentro de variável

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Possuo um form que deverá enviar um e-mail, criei um arquivo chamado **email.php** para criar essa função.

```html
?php

$nome = $_REQUEST['name'];
$fone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$para = "teste@teste.com.br";
$assunto = "Contato pelo site";
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

 if ($url == "MEULINK/administracao.html") {
  $curso = "Administração";
 } elseif ($url == "MEULINK/ciencias-contabeis.html") {
  $curso = "Ciências Contábeis";
 } elseif ($url == "MEU LINK/landing-page/neurociencia.html") {
  $curso = "Neurociência";
 }

 $corpo = "<html><b>Contato pelo site</b><br><br>
 <b>Curso: </b> $curso<br>
 <b>Nome: </b> $nome<br>
 <b>Telefone: </b> $fone</br>
 <b>Email: </b> $email </html>"
 ;

 $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8";
 $header .= "From: $email Reply-to: $email";

mail($para, $assunto, $corpo, $header);

header("location:$url?msg=enviado")
?>
```

No caso, o **$curso** funciona apenas para a primeira condição. Se o link for /ciencias-contabeis.html ele não recebe o que há dentro de $curso

Comment: Meu conselho é que você não use comparações com string pois é possível o velho falso/positivo. Inclui no html um campo hidden e a crie uma logica para passar ele no seu form contendo um id do curso. assim creio que será melhor pra gerenciar. Outra dica é vc colocar um var_dump antes dos ifs pra scannear o que tá chegando

Comment: @IsraelZebulon tem alguma dica de como fazer? Não entendi o falso ou positivo.

Comment: falso positivo as comparacoes com string podem dizer que nao existe pois algum caracter foi mau interpretado. Por hora faz um vardump antes do isfs e testa os tres casos veja o que ta chegando na variavel.